# boost-asio reverse proxy

Tags: c++, networking, boost

I wrote reverse proxy using boost::asio. The idea is to send client's data to two external servers and send back response from one of them. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// BOOST ASIO declarations
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
using namespace boost;
using namespace boost::asio;
using namespace boost::asio::ip;

#include <Windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>

#include <strsafe.h>
#include <Winerror.h>

char szServerBuffer[4096]; // Server buffer will be forwarded to client. 4K.
char szClientBuffer[4096]; // Client buffer will be forwarded to server. 4K.

// Client write Handler.
void writeclient_handler(const boost::system::error_code& ec, std::size_t bytes_transferred)
{

}

// Server write Handler.
void write_handler(const boost::system::error_code& ec, std::size_t bytes_transferred)
{

}

void second_connect_handler(const boost::system::error_code& ec,
    boost::shared_ptr<tcp::socket>& pClientSocket,
    boost::shared_ptr<tcp::socket>& pPeerSocket)
{

}

// Client read handler. As soon as the client receives data, this function is notified.
// Data is forwarded to the server and initiates for further client read asynchronously.
void readclient_handler(const boost::system::error_code& ec, std::size_t bytes_transferred,
    boost::shared_ptr<tcp::socket>& pClientSocket, boost::shared_ptr<tcp::socket>& pPeerSocket)
{
    if (!ec || bytes_transferred != 0)
    {
        pPeerSocket->async_write_some(boost::asio::buffer(szClientBuffer, bytes_transferred),
            boost::bind(write_handler, boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));

        pClientSocket->async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer
        (szClientBuffer, sizeof(szClientBuffer)),
            boost::bind(readclient_handler, boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred,
                pClientSocket, pPeerSocket));
    }
}

// Client connect handler. When the client is connected to the 
// external server, this function is triggered.
void connect_handler(const boost::system::error_code& ec,
    boost::shared_ptr<tcp::socket>& pClientSocket,
    boost::shared_ptr<tcp::socket>& pPeerSocket)
{
    if (!ec)
    {
        pClientSocket->async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer
        (szClientBuffer, sizeof(szClientBuffer)),
            boost::bind(readclient_handler, boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred,
                pClientSocket, pPeerSocket));
    }
}

// Server read handler. As soon as the server receives data, this function is notified.
// Data is forwarded to the client and initiates for further server read asynchronously.
void read_handler(const boost::system::error_code& ec, std::size_t bytes_transferred,
    boost::shared_ptr<tcp::socket>& pPeerSocket, boost::shared_ptr<tcp::socket>& pClientSocket, boost::shared_ptr<tcp::socket>& pSecondClientSocket)
{
    if (!ec || bytes_transferred != 0)
    {
        pClientSocket->async_write_some(boost::asio::buffer(szServerBuffer, bytes_transferred),
            boost::bind(writeclient_handler, boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));

        pSecondClientSocket->async_write_some(boost::asio::buffer(szServerBuffer, bytes_transferred),
            boost::bind(writeclient_handler, boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));

        pPeerSocket->async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer
        (szServerBuffer, sizeof(szServerBuffer)),
            boost::bind(read_handler, boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred,
                pPeerSocket, pClientSocket, pSecondClientSocket));
    }
}

// Server accept handler. When the external client connects the server,
// this function is triggered.
void accept_handler(const boost::system::error_code& ec,
    boost::shared_ptr<io_context>& pIOContext,
    boost::shared_ptr<tcp::acceptor>& pAcceptor,
    boost::shared_ptr<tcp::socket>& pPeerSocket)
{
    if (!ec)
    {
        boost::shared_ptr<tcp::socket> pNewPeerSocket(new tcp::socket(*pIOContext));
        pAcceptor->async_accept(*pNewPeerSocket,
            boost::bind(accept_handler, boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                pIOContext, pAcceptor, pNewPeerSocket));

        boost::shared_ptr<tcp::resolver> pClientResolver(new tcp::resolver(*pIOContext));
        boost::shared_ptr<tcp::resolver::query> pClientFirstServerResolverQuery(
            new tcp::resolver::query("127.0.0.1", boost::lexical_cast<string>(27015)));
        boost::shared_ptr<tcp::resolver::query> pClientSecondServerResolverQuery(
            new tcp::resolver::query("127.0.0.1", boost::lexical_cast<string>(27016)));
        tcp::resolver::iterator itrFirstEndPoint = pClientResolver->resolve(*pClientFirstServerResolverQuery);
        tcp::resolver::iterator itrSecondEndPoint = pClientResolver->resolve(*pClientSecondServerResolverQuery);

        // Client
        boost::shared_ptr<tcp::socket> pFirstServerCientSocket(new tcp::socket(*pIOContext));
        boost::shared_ptr<tcp::socket> pSecondServerCientSocket(new tcp::socket(*pIOContext));
        
        pFirstServerCientSocket->async_connect(*itrFirstEndPoint,
            boost::bind(connect_handler, boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                pFirstServerCientSocket, pPeerSocket));
        pSecondServerCientSocket->async_connect(*itrSecondEndPoint,
            boost::bind(second_connect_handler, boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                pSecondServerCientSocket, pPeerSocket));
        Sleep(2000);

        pPeerSocket->async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer
        (szServerBuffer, sizeof(szServerBuffer)),
            boost::bind(read_handler, boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred,
                pPeerSocket, pFirstServerCientSocket, pSecondServerCientSocket));
    }
}

// Keep the server running.
void ReverProxyThread(boost::shared_ptr<io_context>& pIOContext)
{
    while (1)
    {
        try
        {
            boost::system::error_code ec;
            pIOContext->run(ec);
            break;
        }
        catch (std::runtime_error& ex)
        {

        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int port = 5800;
    // IOContext
    boost::shared_ptr<io_context> pIOContext(new io_context());
    boost::shared_ptr<io_context::strand> pStrand(new io_context::strand(*pIOContext));

    // Worker Thread
    boost::shared_ptr<io_context::work> pWork(new io_context::work(*pIOContext));
    boost::shared_ptr<boost::thread_group> pTG(new boost::thread_group());
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        pTG->create_thread(boost::bind(ReverProxyThread, pIOContext));
    }

    // Resolver
    boost::shared_ptr<tcp::resolver> pResolver(new tcp::resolver(*pIOContext));
    boost::shared_ptr<tcp::resolver::query>
        pQuery(new tcp::resolver::query(tcp::v4(), boost::lexical_cast<string>(port)));
    tcp::resolver::iterator pIter = pResolver->resolve(*pQuery);
    boost::shared_ptr<tcp::acceptor> pAcceptor(new tcp::acceptor(*pIOContext));

    // Acceptor
    tcp::endpoint Endpoint = (*pIter);
    pAcceptor->open(Endpoint.protocol());
    pAcceptor->bind(*pIter);
    pAcceptor->listen();
    boost::shared_ptr<tcp::socket> pPeerSocket(new tcp::socket(*pIOContext));
    pAcceptor->async_accept(*pPeerSocket,
        boost::bind(accept_handler, boost::asio::placeholders::error,
            pIOContext, pAcceptor, pPeerSocket));

    cin.get();

    system::error_code ec;
    pPeerSocket->close(ec);
    pPeerSocket->shutdown(tcp::socket::shutdown_both, ec);

    pIOContext->stop();

    pTG->join_all();
}
```

It seems that code works correctly, however due to I'm new to asio I'd like someone to look through my code and tell what should be improved or fixed.